# How to get a movie clip from one position to another over the course of 11700 frames?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I'm trying to make a movie clip move from X24.5 to X275, and from Y400 to Y100, but over the course of 11700 frames, or 6.5 minutes. I've been trying this for hours, but to no avail. I bet the answer is really simple, but I haven't been able to figure it out. Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You could tween it, using Flash's built in [tween](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/transitions/Tween.html) methods, or you could try my preference of [Greensock's TweenLite](http://www.greensock.com/tweenlite/).

The difference in code is as follows:

**Flash Default Tween**

```
import fl.transitions.Tween;
import fl.transitions.TweenEvent;
import fl.transitions.easing.*;

myTween = new Tween(myObj, "x", Regular.easeIn, startingX, endingX, animationTiming, true);
myTween.addEventListener(TweenEvent.MOTION_FINISH, functionToCall);
```

**TweenLite:**

```
import com.greensock.TweenLite;
import com.greensock.easing.*;

TweenLite.to(myObj, aniTiming, {x:endingX, ease:Regular.easeIn, onComplete:functionToCall});
```